# Exclude multiple Directories while using Copy-Item

Tags: powershell, copy, exclude

**Objective:** Copy all subfolder contents in **C:\TestEnv** to itself.

**From**

```
C:\TestEnv\Folder1\*
C:\TestEnv\Folder1\Testfile1.txt
C:\TestEnv\Folder1\Testfile2.tpdf
C:\TestEnv\Folder2\*
C:\TestEnv\Folder2\Testfile3.txt
C:\TestEnv\Folder2\Testfile4.pdf
```

**To**

```
C:\TestEnv\
C:\TestEnv\Testfile1.txt
C:\TestEnv\Testfile2.tpdf
C:\TestEnv\Testfile3.txt
C:\TestEnv\Testfile4.pdf
```

What I have so far...

```
$Exclude = 'C:\TestEnv\Scripts','C:\TestEnv\TestFiles'

Copy-Item -Exclude $Exclude -Path "C:\TestEnv\*\*" -Destination "C:\TestEnv" -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `-Exclude` doesn't get arrays, Try this:

```
$Exclude = 'C:\TestEnv\Scripts','C:\TestEnv\TestFiles'
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TestEnv\*" -directory |
  where {$_.fullname -notin $Exclude} |
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
  Foreach {
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Destination "C:\TestEnv\" -force
  }
```

Here:

- Define Exclusion array as `$Exclude`.
- Filter directories from source using `Get-ChildItem` and `-Directory` switch.
- Filter the exclusion directories with `where`.
- Again list only files with `-File` and recursive with `-Recurse`.
- Then `Copy-Item` forcefully (`-Force` omittable) in a `Foreach` loop piped the files.

Comment: That seemed to work but it skipped Folder2 contents & only copied Folder1

Comment: scratch that. It only copied 1 file from each of the folders instead of all of them.

Comment: @LexPointOh I tested it, and  for testing I took a directory with about 7 sub folders and 500 files and the all expected ones were copied to the top. Make sure you're using exact code.

Comment: Interesting, when I run it. It only copies 1 out of each of the subdirectories. I copied the code without modifying it.

Comment: Do the filenames contain any charactters besides letters and/or digits? Try changing `Copy-Item $_.Fullname ...` to `Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname ...`.

Comment: @KeithMiller Actually yes, they do. Testing now....

Comment: @KeithMiller That definitely fixed it! TY!!! Is this the equivalent to a full path vs a relative path almost? Except this is talking about file names.

Comment: Not really. It's about not interpreting characters as wildcards. When you look at the help for a cmdlet, you'll see that the `-Path` parameter "Accepts [wildcards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1)". In addition to the familiar "*" & "?", **PowerSehll** borrows from regular expressions and interprets brackets, `[` & `]`, as wildcard operaors that define a range or set of allwoed characters. If brackets are part of a foldername or filename, you need to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter.

Comment: @WasifHasan: You're welcome. It can be less than obvious when you don't have representative sample data! :D